# Is there any SLAM method based on Octomap representation?

Tags: slam, octomap, octomap-mapping, 3d-slam, 3dslam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know what I am saying here is not precise.I know Octomap is a 3D occupancy grid mapping approach based on an octree and there are some SLAM methods that works based on 2D occupancy grids. E.g. Gmapping: a 2D grid-based SLAM algorithm that provides a 2-D occupancy grid map from laser and pose data collected by a mobile robot and Hector SLAM: a 2D grid-based SLAM algorithm that provides a 2-D occupancy grid map using combination of high update 2D mapping and 6DOF pose estimation.

I wanted to know is there any available package (or publication) that tries to use octomap representation to tackle SLAM problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194607/is-there-any-slam-method-based-on-octomap-representation?/) by [AliAs](https://answers.ros.org/users/20060/alias/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2014-10-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes there is, you can see here :

---

F. Endres, J. Hess, J. Sturm, D. Cremers, and W. Burgard. [3-d mapping with an rgb-d camera](https://vision.in.tum.de/_media/spezial/bib/endres2013tro.pdf). Robotics, IEEE Transactions on, 30(1) :177–187, Feb 2014.

---

F. Endres, J. Hess, N. Engelhard, J. Sturm, D. Cremers, and W. Burgard. An evaluation of the rgb-d slam system. In Robotics and Automa-tion (ICRA), 2012 IEEE International Conference on, pages 1691–1696, May 2012.

---

Good luck

---

Originally posted by [slamonline](https://answers.ros.org/users/18927/slamonline/) with karma: 36 on 2014-10-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AliAs](https://answers.ros.org/users/20060/alias/) on 2014-10-10**:
Thank you. I saw the first paper and it seems they did every thing (e.g. extracting visual features, ...) using point clouds and next used Octomap to just reduce the map size.
I added this, just to clarify the subject for future readers.